# Support MySQL find_in_set Multi-Valued Indexes

Tags: mysql, find-in-set

Since MySQL version 8.0.17 there is **[Multi-Valued Indexes](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/create-index.html#create-index-multi-valued)** for JSON array column, is there also a simple possibility to create **Multi-Valued Indexes** for comma delimited string column (CHAR, VARCHAR, ...) to increase the performance of `FIND_IN_SET` function?

I know that there is an option to create a secondary table `customers_zip` and use the `INNER JOIN` or `IN` function, but this is a complicated option. I use 10k databases whit ~150 various tables -> ~1.5M different comma delimited columns.

Example table:

```
CREATE TABLE `customers` (
 `id` BIGINT NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT PRIMARY KEY,
 `zip_string` VARCHAR(100) NOT NULL,
 `zip_json` JSON,
 INDEX `zip_json` ((CAST(`zip_json` AS UNSIGNED ARRAY)))
);
```

Insert 1 000 000 rows:

```
INSERT INTO `customers` (`id`, `zip_string`, `zip_json`) VALUES 
 (1, '10001,10002,10003', '[10001,10002,10003]'),
 (2, '10004,10005', '[10004,10005]'),
 ...;
```

Select for `FIND_IN_SET` load **120ms**

```
SELECT * FROM `customers` WHERE FIND_IN_SET('10005', `zip_string`);
```

Select for `JSON_CONTAINS` or `MEMBER OF` load **1ms**

```
SELECT * FROM `customers` WHERE JSON_CONTAINS(`zip_json`, '10005');
SELECT * FROM `customers` WHERE 10005 MEMBER OF(`zip_json`);
```

Answer (score 2):

No, you can't make any kind of index to optimize searches for arbitrary elements in a comma-separated list.

The closest options are:

- Convert the comma-separated list to a JSON array, and make a multi-valued index, however in current versions of MySQL this only works for integers. There is no support for making a multi-valued index of strings.
- Use a functional index, but this only works for a fixed search criteria. That is, you could add index on the expression `(FIND_IN_SET('10005', zip_string))`, but the value 10005 is hard-coded in the index definition. It's not useful to find any other value.
- Use a fulltext index, but this has limitations too.

It really is easier to optimize if you refactor to a normalized table design, storing individual values in their own row. Storing comma-separated lists working against the strengths of a relational database.

Answer (score 0):

I created a little hack :)

Add a virtual JSON array column `zip_index`, whose contents will be automatically generated from the `zip_string` column, and which will be **Multi-Valued Indexes**

```
ALTER TABLE `customers` ADD COLUMN `zip_index`
   JSON GENERATED ALWAYS AS (CONCAT('[', `zip_string`, ']'))
      VIRTUAL NOT NULL;
```

```
CREATE INDEX `zip_index` ON `customers` ((CAST(`zip_index` AS UNSIGNED ARRAY)));
```

Select for `JSON_CONTAINS` load **2ms**

```
SELECT * FROM `customers` WHERE JSON_CONTAINS(`zip_index`, '10005');
```

The content in column `zip_index` is automatically generated and indexed when using `UPDATE` on column `zip_string` or `INSERT` a new row (mabey reduced performance?). But it is not necessary to use multiple tables for each similar column (comma delimiter string). Using the `JSON_CONTAINS` function is still as easy as the `FIND_IN_SET` function.

---

Example for indexing non-integer lists

```
CREATE INDEX `zip_index` ON `customers` ((CAST(`zip_index` AS CHAR(100) ARRAY)));
```

The content of the original column `zip_string` must contain strings enclosed in quotes, like `"A10001","B10002","C10003"`